# No me inserta los datos hacia una función con POST

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, insertar

Estoy intentando hacer de forma autonoma mi primer inserto a bases de datos, he insertado de la misma manera pero guiandome de videos anteriormente en la misma pagina desde un registro de usuarios.

El problema lo tengo en ValidadorEconomia por que me devuelve un array vacio y nose por que, aqui os dejo un ejemplo de lo que me devuelven los dos arrays de $dni y $validador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AñadirEconomia Aqui tengo el codigo de la pagina principal:

```
if (isset($_POST["economia"])){
    Conexion::abrir_conexion();

    $dni = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_dni(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']);
    $validador = new ValidadorEconomia($_POST["ingreso"], $_POST["gasto"], $_POST["nota"], Conexion :: obtener_conexion());
    echo json_encode($dni);
    echo json_encode($validador);
    if ($validador -> economia_valida()){
             //Aquí tiene que entrar
    }
    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
}

<div class="card-body">
                           <form role="form" method="post"
                           action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                               <?php
                               if(!isset($_POST["economia"])){
                               include_once "economia_vacio.inc.php";
                               }
                               ?>
                           </form>
                          </div>
```

economia_accion:

```
echo $_POST["ingreso"];
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST["gasto"];
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST["nota"];
echo "<br>";
```

ValidadorEconomia:

```
class ValidadorEconomia {
    private $ingreso;
    private $gasto;
    private $nota;

    public function __construct($ingreso, $gasto, $nota, $conexion)
    {
        $this -> ingreso = "";
        $this -> gasto = "";
        $this -> nota = "";
    }

public function economia_valida(){
        if($this -> ingreso === "" ||
            $this -> gasto === ""){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Veo que no se ejecuta correctamente al ver que no añade la linea, pero llega a la redireccion por lo q el boton es, no veo el fallo en eso si que tienes razon e intentado sacarlo pero no sabia como. Estoy aprendiendo de forma autodidacta asi que cualquier ayuda es buena.

Comment: Lo que creo q sucede es que no me llega a hacer bien el post en validadoreconomia o la variable $dni, por q las dos sentencias siguientes deben de funcionar

Comment: He llegado a que en el array de $validador no se guarda ningun dato, mañana sigo.

Comment: Los comentarios sólo son para quienes pidan aclaraciones. SI tienes algo que añadir, debes [edit] la pregunta. Los comentarios se pierden

Comment: Nos has dejado todo tu código para que hagamos lo que debiste haber hecho tú: depurar, identificar dónde ocurre el problema y tratar de resolverlo. Y si no puedes, ahí entramos nosotros. Nos dirás: *he probado esto y esto y lo otro, aquí tengo este resultado y aquí tengo este otro que es nulo o vacío o da tal error*. Entonces nosotros analizaremos ese trozo de código y te diremos, *tienes mal tal cosa*, o si no se ve el problema ahí te diremos, *muéstranos tal función o tal clase*. Es por eso que SO pide que en las preguntas se aporte un Ejemplo **Mínimo** y Verificable.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo pero nose por que no me coge los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tenia en esta funcion, no estaba añadiendo ningun valor.

```
public function __construct($ingreso, $gasto, $nota, $conexion)
    {
        $this -> ingreso = "";
        $this -> gasto = "";
        $this -> nota = "";
    }
```

EL codigo correcto seria asi:

```
        $this -> ingreso = $ingreso;
        $this -> gasto = $gasto;
        $this -> nota = $nota;
```

Y para mostrar la cadena usaremos:

```
var_dump($validador);
```